# Symfony 3 show me the same error that I already fixed

Tags: symfony

I had this error on a twig file:
Variable "myVariable" does not exist.

the line in the file was:

```
{{ myVariable }}
```

I fixed the error:

```
{% if myVariable is defined %}
{{ myVariable }}
{% endif %}
```

But it showed me the same error
So I deleted the cache in two ways:

- php bin/console cache:clear -e dev
- deleting manually all the files from the cache/dev folder

But it showed me the same error

How is it possible to fix it?

thanks

ps
I'm using symfony 3 with IIS 8

Comment: Are you sure you are looking in the right place?

Comment: well I'm new with symfony. the app_dev showed me the exact row of the error, that was in the twig file. I fixed it and it still show me the same line with the same error.

Comment: Are you editing files on your local filesystem?

Comment: yes, I'm using all on my personal computer on localhost. I disabled the cache both on IIS and on chrome, and now symfony seems to work correctly on the app_dev, but still on app.php it doesn't get the changes on twigs file

Comment: even when I delete all the cache the app.php show me the old twig file

Comment: what do you do to delete the cache ?

Comment: I delete all the file in var\cache or execute the php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod